# Finding position of clicked item to download from Google Cloud Storage on Android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-storage

I am currently trying to display the file names of all files in a specific folder in Google Cloud Storage in a listview and download the file once the file name is clicked.
However, I am unable to find the position of the file inside the OnItemClick listener, so the last item in the folder is being downloaded for each of the items in the ListView. How can I find the position to download the correct item?

This is my code for displaying and clicking the items:

```
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    listRef = storage.getInstance().getReference("uploads" + "/" + ID);
    listRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
            for (StorageReference items : listResult.getItems()) {
                arrayList.add(items.getName());

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                        items.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
                                String url = items.getDownloadUrl().toString();

                                filename = items.getName();

                                DownloadFromUrl(uri);

                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you want to find the index position of an item you want to download. Correct me if I am wrong.

```java
arrayList.indexOf("value"); // index = 3
```

This will return -1 if the item does not exist.

To get the last element you want to do something like this.

```java
arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Hi, my problem is I am unable to get the position of the element the user has clicked so the download URL for the file is the same for all files displayed. I am unsure how to pass in the item I want to get the download URL for.

Comment: I see. You might find this helpful to search for [Java snippets](https://www.codota.com/code) that you could check your code against.